# How to set TO ADDRESS for email in Oracle Warehouse Builder process flow

Tags: oracle-warehouse-builder

One of the developers just left the company and all the notification emails in OWB were directed to his email address, Can you please help me on how to change the TO ADDRESS for the email in the process flow.

Thank you,
Sabelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using OWB 11.2, you should:

1. Open your process flow in the OWB Design Center
2. Make sure that the "Structure" pane is visible, otherwise click on `View -> Structure`
3. Make sure that the "Property Inspector" pane is visible, otherwise click on `View -> Property Inspector`
4. Click on the Email Activity
5. In the Structure pane click on the `TO_ADDRESS` property of the Email Activity
6. In the Property Inspector pane change the value of the `TO_ADDRESS` property to the new email address

See also the [Email Activity](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e10935/activities_in_pf.htm#WBETL27006) documentation.